# Is there any difference between antennas applications?

Tags: pcb, antenna, lora

I'm thinking of adding LoRa module to the PCB I designed, and I chose an antenna.

[NN02-201](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/ignion/NN02-201/11619358)

The reason I chose this antenna is because I can easily find it in the country I live in.

However, LoRa is not written in the description of this antenna. Is the task of each antenna different? Can I choose **any** antenna with the frequency I need and complete the PCB?

Comment: A piece of wire with the right length is an antenna. Antennas are passive components and parts with similar, or better yet, identical specifications are interchangeable.

Comment: @LiorBilia, Then I can use any antenna by looking at properties like dbi, frequency etc...

Comment: That's a good starting point.  Frequency, bandwidth, directivity and return loss would be good specs to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in theory you can choose any antenna that works in the frequency band of interest, but the chip antenna you've specified (like most electrically-small antennas) has an important caveat:

Chip antennas are highly dependent on the overall PCB design, including impedance matching networks, the feed trace, any radiating trace(s), the position of the antenna on the PCB, and the PCB ground plane size and shape.

You will need to consult more in-depth datasheets to design with this chip antenna.